# "I want to add your Birthday" app

Tags: facebook-apps

Now and again I receive requests from friends that they want to add my birthday to their calendar using the "I want to add your birthday" app, is this an explicit request from the friend or is this app using personal attributes without permission for an exploitative purpose, if it's the latter then are you breaking the law?

Comment: related [What are the benefits of using the "I want to add your birthday" app on Facebook?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37036)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a useless app. I've not accepted any requests - Facebook already has the ability to post your birthday and alert your friends to that event.

The app doesn't appear to be illegal or noted by Facebook as spam (yet).

Read more here:  http://www.businessinsider.com/mycalendar-facebook-app-2013-1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't responded either, duplicate function of home pg birthday notifications, plus My droid calendar auto- added everyone on Facebook (It didn't use the add bday app, as far as I can tell)

It is spam IMO

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Your answer is however a comment. Earn up to 50 reputation to place comments. Read the [faq] area.